# PHPUnit with clover: class PHP_Token_OPEN_TAG not found

Tags: php, magento, phpunit

I am running PHP unit as follows:

```
phpunit --debug --verbose --coverage-clover=/tmp/test.xml
```

and get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PHP_Token_OPEN_TAG' not found in /opt/pear/share/pear/PHP/Token/Stream.php on line 205
```

The stack trace leads down to

```
12. PHP_Token_Stream->scan($sourceCode = '<?php\n/**\n...') /opt/pear/share/pear/PHP/Token/Stream.php:147
```

The source code is syntactically okay.

This class is defined in `/opt/pear/share/pear/PHP/Token.php` but it looks like it can not be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dumped the output of spl_autoload_functions() in Stream.php:147 and found out, that there is some Aitoc autoloader.

The problem is caused by an Aitoc Magento extension.

They have a function that simply unregisters all autoloaders.

```
$autoloaders = spl_autoload_functions();
if ($autoloaders and is_array($autoloaders) && !empty($autoloaders))
{
    foreach ($autoloaders as $autoloader)
    {
        spl_autoload_unregister($autoloader);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a versioning / autoloading Problem as the token package or the code coverage package might not be installed/updated correctly.

Give

```
(sudo) pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/phpunit
```

a try. That usually fixes those "strange errors".

Comment: Unfortunately that does not help. Also other projects on the same server do not cause that problem.